# Notification count doesn't match displayed number of notifications

Tags: bug, notifications

I think this is a bit of a disconnect:

[image]

The badge number is telling me that there should be 12 items to review, while the notification list only displays 4 new items.

That creates a very confusing UX.  It's like having a mail client that says "12 new messages", but then only lets you see 4 of them.  You're liable to drive yourself insane trying to find the "missing" 8 messages.

After looking into the notifications, it appears that what happened is that the notification list merged multiple comment notifications into a single notification.  That's fine, in and of itself, but I think the count also needs to be updated to reflect the merge operation (or else the merged item needs to clearly indicate that it's standing in for multiple notifications).

Specifically, I think that either:

1. When multiple notification events are merged into a single inbox item, the count displayed in the badge should be reduced by a corresponding amount so that the count always exactly matches the number of inbox items.

**Or**

2. When multiple notification events are merged into a single inbox item, the inbox item should clearly indicate how many separate events it is standing in for.  So for instance, if 9 comments have been merged into a single item in the inbox, then call that item "9 comments" instead of "comment".

**Bottom Line**

The notification count and the number of unread inbox items should always match, if not by simple 1:1 correspondence then by having a clear indication of how much each item contributes to the total notification count.

Comment: Per [marrados's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390795/335251), the number visible over the inbox now reflects the number of visible unread notifications, at least in the places where the [inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251) have been applied (i.e., this might not be true of the chat inbox).