# Alert shows more inbox messages than I have

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications

I apparently had 7 new inbox messages, but when I checked there were only two. I thought that maybe there were multiple messages in one or both of the questions, but that wasn't the case. It looks like a bug to me.

I found a previous question about this with no answers: [Notification count doesn't match displayed number of notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261540/notification-count-doesnt-match-displayed-number-of-notifications)

[image: 7 new messages - only 2 shown]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I count 7 comments:

6 on [Why aren't plants' roots as diverse as leaves?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/41795/5542)

> [image]

1 on [How can light enter a black hole if it cannot get out?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189368/how-can-light-enter-a-black-hole-if-it-cannot-get-out#comment626847_189368)

> [image: comments]

That makes 7.

In your inbox the messages on the same post are collapsed into 1. That is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: My bad! Somehow I didn't notice 6 comments all from the same user (why couldn't they have just written one or two longer comments?). I was under the mistaken impression that going to your profile and checking your inbox would show everything. I found it under my **Network** profile.

Comment: I say it is a bug, because (A) there's no indication within this dropdown that the notification for the plant root question represents 6 comments instead of 1, and (B) clicking on that notification in the dropdown only reduces the inbox icon's count by 1, not by 6.