# New notification system still feels counterintuitive

Tags: discussion, notifications, global-inbox

This has been bugging me for ages—I guess since [October 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382693/inbox-improvements-marking-notifications-as-read-unread-and-a-filtered-inbox-v): while it's good that the notifications were made more "sticky", I sometimes feel they are a bit *too* sticky. It's hard to pin down the problem precisely, but the user interface is still a bit counterintuitive, even for an experienced user after half a year.

Specifically, if someone posts two replies to one of my questions or answers, then I get two notifications in my inbox. So, I click on one of them, read both replies, and then I'm happy, right?

But now I still have one notification in my inbox. I've read it, but it's "unread", and I always have to spend a couple of minutes working out how to make it go away.

I know that I can press "mark all as read", but for some reason I never see or think of that button. So I end up having to click on the "unread" notification, thus reloading the page that I'm already looking at, just to make it go away.

In writing this post, I realised that I can also click on the little envelope icons next to each post to mark them as read individually. This is probably really useful. But I decided to post this anyway, because in seven months it never occurred to me that those icons might be clickable, and I'm sure I can't be the only one.

TL;DR: after half a year I still find the new notification UI frustrating and counterintuitive sometimes, and I wonder if it might be worth revisiting the user experience a bit.

---

I also want to mention that my habit is always to option-click on the notifications, opening them in a new tab behind the current one, then go through each tab one by one. My expectation is that having done that I will no longer have any notifications left, but in fact I often do. It might be that this habit of mine is causing my issue somehow. But I don't want to change it—I think it's a reasonable way to use the system and should be supported.

Comment: related: [Better handling of inbox notifications that have been merged together](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386915/better-handling-of-inbox-notifications-that-have-been-merged-together)

Comment: @rene thanks - that question helps me understand why I've been so confused by this system. (My question is quite close to being a duplicate of that one I guess.)

Comment: @N.Virgo depends, if that's your only concern then yes, it's duplicate. If not, and you have more issues, add them and it won't be a dupe.

Comment: Yeah, the post I linked is a feature request. I think your question can be the invitation for the UX designer to explain the use case that lead to the current implementation.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard well, my issue is mostly that the user interface doesn't make it obvious how to make read-but-"unread" notifications go away, which I guess is a different issue from the way they get merged together, which I hadn't noticed. But the merging issue is probably a big part of why I kept being so confused, all the same.

Comment: @N.Virgo about option-click, it was also reported somewhere, for some reason the code doesn't "listen" to it correctly, so not marking as read. If you have middle button (wheel) in the mouse, clicking it will open in a new tab and mark as read.

Comment: Anyway, better leave this open as open discussion. Personally I'm not affected as I have a bizarre habit and not marking anything as read. :-D (So currently have 893 "unread" items.)